# Can I use the Cognito User Pool Group in S3 Bucket policies?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

So I just read half the internet and I think I have a pretty good grab on everything that is possible. I still have one issue though for my use-case.

My requirements: I have users that are managed in Cognito, those users are in groups that are currently only managed in my application. I want to provide access to a S3 bucket only to members of the group.

From what I understand what I could do is to manage these Groups also in Cognito, add a IAM Role to that Group and then have a bucket policy that set's the permission.

According to [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_s3_cognito-bucket.html) I can use `${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}` to make sure that a given user only has access to this "subfolder" in S3. The docs are sparse, but besides `sub` there is apparantly only `aud` and `amr` which are both not helpful in my case.

There is a lot of stuff about fine grained permissions on the Web, but nothing on group level permissions. Apparently groups are a newer Cognito feature but that can only used to assign IAM Roles and nothing else in the eco-system?

Comment: Given that one can only have 25 groups per pool that idea also does not seem to work. Is there any way to group users for IAM auth purposes?

Comment: This [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-cognito-groups-and-fine-grained-role-based-access-control-2/) might be plausible for your use-case.

Comment: @lightyagami Not really, their notion of fine grained access control is that you have two groups, not an infinite amount due to business requirements.

Comment: Anything has changed for last 2 years? Is it possible to manage Cognito groups in S3 access policy?

Comment: @ruhungry so funny you asked this question 20 minutes ago... that's exactly the time that I've been researching for this issue.. no progress so far :(

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is no real solution. We now work with a hybrid approach, using the Cognito way to allow per user write permissions and per (custom) group presigned S3 links to allow read access. This way we have to manage the read access in the application, but that's at least easier than doing it all manually.

Comment: I wonder if you are still handling it that way. 2 years has passed by and we still don't have a solution for it? :(

Comment: Sorry, not on that project anymore, so I can not tell you if that has changed.